# Jenkins artifactory plugin not including artifacts for docker images

Tags: docker, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I am using the *artifactory plugin (v3.4.1) in jenkins (2.x)*. My build job builds a docker image among other things.

I am using the ***rtDockerPush*** step to push my image up to the registry. I am hoping that this will update the build info to add a new module and its associated artifacts.

But the build-info only contains an empty module with no artifacts. What could be the issue here?

I used the **jfrog cli** to push the docker image and then publish the build info. That works as expected. The module lists the different image layers as artifacts.

Comment: In case of jenkins with artifactory plugin the build info is published via the artifactory plugin check box option "Publish Build Info". In case of using rtDockerPush this option won't be available by default. You have to publish this info by declaring it explicitly https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax

Comment: I do explicitly publish build info using rtPublishBuildInfo in a later step. The problem is not with the publish. The problem is that the build info does not have artifacts for the docker image modules.

Comment: @PrasadK I have a similar problem. Have you found a solution?